# How to run a Playframework application using HTTPS?

Tags: ssl, https, playframework, certificate, self-signed

I have to run a Playframework application using HTTPS. What is the simplest way to make that?

Answer (score 0):

Simply start your application with an HTTPS port:

```
./start -Dhttps.port=9443
```

More documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ConfiguringHttps